# Force table cell width/height to fit in div

Tags: css, html-table, size

I've got a grid (7x7 table) of images.
I want to auto-fit that table/grid in to a fluid sized div that adjusts according to monitor display size.
I want the table not to grow past the bounds of the div, neither width nor height, but take up the maximum area while keeping each table cell the same height and width as all other table cells.

I know this might be hard to visualize from my description.  Basically, all table cells need to be forced to an exact square (same width/height), but that size could grow or shrink depending on how big the display size is.  And none of the table should go outside the visible screen area for that div.

It's easy to force width: 100% .. but then height could be too large.
I'd like to do this in css, but I'm open to anything that works.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need a table for this? Easier with 49 divs (or imgs straight off), floated and width/height 1/7 of the container...

Answer (score 0):

So you would like to have images in table grid and have it respond to window resizing to always fit.

The markup (in this example my grid is 3x3 but works the same for 7x7, just add more data cells and rows).

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6115/6249486517_884b897248_o.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6115/6249486517_884b897248_o.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6115/6249486517_884b897248_o.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6115/6249486517_884b897248_o.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6115/6249486517_884b897248_o.jpg"></td>
           <td><img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6115/6249486517_884b897248_o.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6115/6249486517_884b897248_o.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6115/6249486517_884b897248_o.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6115/6249486517_884b897248_o.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#wrapper{width: 100%;}

#wrapper table {width: 100%;}

#wrapper table tr td {width: 33%;}

#wrapper table tr td img {width: 100%;}
```

Used some random image from Flickr.

Hope it helps.